# Oracle SQL to determine closest date less than an event date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an event table that shows event dates and attendees but a customer now wants to see the titles of attendees at the time of the event.  I have an audit table that shows changes in title and the dates on which the change occurred however I am not sure how to do a SQL statement that would find the title whose date is less than the date of the event but greater than earlier title changes.

**Example:**

In `audit` table I have:

```
name1, title1, 1/23/2011   
name1, title2, 2/1/2012   
name1, title3, 3/1/2013
```

In `event` table I have

```
event1, name1, 3/2/2012  
event2, name1, 1/30/2011  
event3, name1, 6/3/2013  
event4, name1, 5/3/2012
```

Result I want is:

```
event1, name1, title2  -- (event date > 2/1/2012 (title2 date) but < 3/1/2013 (title3 date)   
event2, name1, title1  -- (event date > 1/23/2011 but < other title dates)  
event3, name1, title3  -- (event date > highest title date)  
event4, name1, title2  -- (same as first example above)
```

Is it possible to do with just SQL or is pl/sql required?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_tab (name VARCHAR2(20), title VARCHAR2(20), title_date DATE);
CREATE TABLE event (event_name VARCHAR2(20), person_name VARCHAR2(20), event_date DATE);

INSERT INTO audit_tab VALUES ('name1', 'title1', TO_DATE('01-23-2011', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO audit_tab VALUES ('name1', 'title2', TO_DATE('02-01-2012', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO audit_tab VALUES ('name1', 'title3', TO_DATE('03-01-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));

INSERT INTO event VALUES ('event1', 'name1', TO_DATE('03-02-2012', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('event2', 'name1', TO_DATE('01-30-2011', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('event3', 'name1', TO_DATE('06-03-2013', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));
INSERT INTO event VALUES ('event4', 'name1', TO_DATE('05-03-2012', 'MM-DD-YYYY'));

SELECT e.event_name, e.person_name, a.title
  FROM event e, audit_tab a
WHERE e.person_name = a.name
  AND e.event_date >= a.title_date
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM audit_tab
                  WHERE name = a.name
                    AND title != a.title
                    AND title_date > a.title_date
                    AND title_date <= e.event_date)
ORDER BY e.event_name
;
```

Check it at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a9814a/1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT e.event, a.name, a.title 
FROM audit a
JOIN event e ON a.name=e.name 
WHERE a.date = (SELECT MAX(e.date) FROM audit a1 WHERE a.name = a1.name AND 
      a1.date <= e.date)
ORDER BY e.event;
```

Comment: It does work when you get the brackets right. Checked on my tables: SELECT e.event_name, a.name, a.title
FROM audit_tab a
JOIN event e ON a.name=e.person_name 
WHERE a.title_date = (SELECT MAX(a.title_date) FROM audit_tab a WHERE a.title_date <= e.event_date);

Comment: @Przemyslaw Kruglej - Thank you for testing it. I must be blind but I see nothing wrong with my brackets.  What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing a bracket before the SELECT keyword :) it is there, but just right after it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine:

```
CREATE TABLE T_AUDIT(NAME VARCHAR2(100), TITLE VARCHAR2(100), ADATE DATE);
CREATE TABLE T_EVENT(EVENT VARCHAR2(100), NAME VARCHAR2(100), EDATE DATE);

SELECT te.event, te.name, ta.title FROM T_AUDIT ta INNER JOIN T_EVENT te ON ta.name = te.name
WHERE ta.adate = (SELECT MAX(ta1.adate) FROM T_AUDIT ta1
                  WHERE ta1.name = te.name
                        AND ta1.adate < te.edate)
```